# BIND and DHCPd performance

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, dhcp

I've a little question.

Is there any usual performance matrice on DHCPd and BIND services?

I mean, can I scale my servers depending on my clients numbers and then how?

Can I found somewhere a matrix or something about number of DNS queries per second handle by BIND on a basic server?

Can I found somewhere a matrix or something about number of leases delivers by DHCPd per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIND performance depends on the number of view, amount of memory, percentage of hits in the cache, number of authoritarian zones and types of queries. On not powerful server, BIND can handle 1k-2k queries/second.

DHCP performance depends on the configuration(lease-time, fail-over, call function). For easy configuration(not use match, fail-over, log and other function) DHCP can handle 100K client(lease-time 30 minute).

Comment: Thanks a lot.

About me, Bind should be benchmark on the respond time instead of the number of requests per second, because our server is a Quad Core 2.5Ghz + 4Go DDR ECC and 146Gb of HDD, our Network is a Full Gigabit Grid.
According to those specs, the most limited part of our architecture should be the Network interfaces of the server (2x1Gbps Intel Card) which should delivered at least a 30Mo/s of bandwith.

Am I on the right direction?
How did you found your specs about DHCP and DNS?
Because, even on ISC website there are no info about that.